# Splitting Column wise values into rows

Tags: sql-server, db2-400

I have a table with year and month wise values at column level.

```
Table Structure
----------------
Franchise    Year   Month1 Month2 Month3 Month4 ....Month12
```

Need to fetch values of last six month values from current month through SQL. Can anybody help?

Eg. If I need last six months, It should be current year record with month2 and month1 values as well as 2013 record with Month12, Month11, Month10, Month9 values.

Comment: Looks like you have not optimal table structure. I don't know all your application, but I'll think about a table with four columns: franchise, year, month, value.  For that table structure such queries will be simplier.

Comment: Are you looking for a answer for both Microsoft SQL-Server and IBM DB2 for i?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @MonthStart date
DECLARE @yyyy char(4)
DECLARE @mmm char(3)
DECLARE @monthColumn varchar(7)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @MonthStart = DATEADD(day,1-DAY(getdate()), getdate())

set @MonthStart = DATEADD(month,-6,@MonthStart )
SET @SQL  = 'SELECT Franchise'
WHILE DATEDIFF(month,@MonthStart,GETDATE() )>0
BEGIN
SET @yyyy = DATENAME(yyyy,@MonthStart )
SET @mmm = DATENAME(mm,@MonthStart )
SET @monthColumn = 'Month'+convert(varchar(2),DATEpart(m,@MonthStart ))
SET @SQL  = @SQL +',
SUM(CASE WHEN Year = '+@yyyy+' THEN ['+@monthColumn +'] ELSE NULL END) AS ['+@mmm+' '+@yyyy +']'
set @MonthStart = DATEADD(month,1,@MonthStart )
END 

/*Substitute with the name of the table*/
SET @SQL  = @SQL +'
FROM [TableName] '

/*For demonstration purposes show the SQL to be executes*/
PRINT @SQL  

/*Try to Execute it */
EXEC (@SQL)
```

This will generate and execute a statement along the lines of

```
SELECT Franchise,
SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2013 THEN [Month8] ELSE NULL END) AS [Aug 2013],
SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2013 THEN [Month9] ELSE NULL END) AS [Sep 2013],
SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2013 THEN [Month10] ELSE NULL END) AS [Oct 2013],
SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2013 THEN [Month11] ELSE NULL END) AS [Nov 2013],
SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2013 THEN [Month12] ELSE NULL END) AS [Dec 2013],
SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2014 THEN [Month1] ELSE NULL END) AS [Jan 2014]
FROM [TableName]
```